# jQuery Ajax POST request never completes

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a long running process that takes about 13-15 minutes to finish. The problem is that, the "complete" and "success" events are never executed. I can confirm from back end that the process has finished (can see updated time stamps in sql table), but on front end, the loading icon keeps spinning.

When I check the Network tab in IE Developer Tools, that specific request remains in "pending" state forever. Interestingly, if I run the same process in Firefox, it correctly execute the complete and success events.

Here is the code (pretty standard post request):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //Do something
        },
        complete: function () {
            $('#overlay').hide();
        },
        success: function (retMessage) {
            //reload page data
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: And do you return something from the server, terminating the request and such ?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have a web client sitting around with an open connection for 15 minutes either way.  How about having the server side spawn a thread, and then have a recurring check from the client side to see if the task is done?

Comment: 13-15 minutes is *far* too long for an HTTP request to wait.  Queue up the action on the server in some way and return a response of some kind.  Use web sockets, long polling, or just checking the status of the process each time a page loads in order to report the status back to the user.  But a browser can't be expected to wait that long for a web server to respond.

Comment: @adeneo, I just return a string message from server, Thanks

Comment: @Dave thanks for your suggestion, will try to implement something like that.

Comment: @David, thanks for your suggestion.